# Unable to find explicit activity class in manifest for external library

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need to add an activity tag for an external library I'm using, per their documentation, but when I do that using this code

```
<activity
            android:name="com.adityaanand.morphdialog.MorphDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MorphDialog.Custom.Light">
</activity>
```

in my application tag, I get the error

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.jggdevelopment.simpleweather/in.adityaanand.morphdialog.MorphDialogActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

How can I include an external library's activity in my manifest file?

[This](https://github.com/AdityaAnand1/Morphing-Material-Dialogs) is the library.

Comment: Your error says `in.adityaanand.morphdialog.MorphDialogActivity` - that doesn't match the `com.` start of the class. Where is the `in.` prefix coming from?

Comment: Not a clue, I thought the same thing.  I'm just implementing it in my apps gradle file like any other library.  Where should I be looking for that package?

Comment: When I go to Packages view, under Libraries, it is listed as `in.adityaanand.morphdialog`

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change the activity name to `in.adityaanand.morphdialog.MorphDialogActivity` and it worked.  I thought I had tried that already, but I guess not.

Comment: Can you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792660/exporting-cocos2d-android-application-as-aar-and-calling-its-activity-from-anoth   I have the same issue but a little weird. Please help