# Exporting cocos2d Android application as aar and calling its Activity from another project

Tags: android, android-studio, aar, cocos2d-android, cocoscreator

I had built a cocos2d Android project from cocos creator. (sample application)

And I exported this android application as an android library (sample.aar)

I created another Android application (MyDemo) and imported the android library (sample.aar)

I am calling the AppActivity of (sample.aar) library from the MainActivity of (MyDemo) application on Button click

```
aarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.cocos2d.demo", "org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity"));
       startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

The result is MyDemo app crashed.

Below is the error message I get in the console

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.cocos2d.demo/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Below the screenshot of the error
[image]

**#But there is a trick**

If I install the (sample) application on the phone first and then create an aar and import in the MyDemo application, then it works fine.

But I don't want to do like this.

I am stuck with this for couple of days.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please show how did you add dependencies?

Comment: Project Structure > Modules > + > Import .JAR/.AAR package > Select package > Finish 

Project Structure > Dependencies > app > + > Module Dependency > Select Imported module

Apply Changes
Sync Project with Gradle files